# Linq To Sql: Retrieving a parent entity without the children attached

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

I have a parent entity that is tied to a ton of child entities.

Is there a way in linq to sql to only grab the parent entity without the rest of the children attached?

Comment: When you query for the parent entity without fetching the children specifically, parent entity is all you get. The children will be retrieved lazily, and only if you choose to enumerate them on the parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way in linq to sql to only grab the parent entity without the rest of the children attached?

LINQ to SQL utilizes deferred loading by default. It won't load the child collections unless you iterate over them.

To turn off deferred loading, set `DataContext.DeferredLoadingEnabled` to false.

Comment: I gave you the answer because I think you are right... come to find out my question was not really relevant to my problem..  I just ended up going a different route.